# SONARQUBE C++ community plugin 9.0 and lower unavailable

Tags: c++, sonarqube

It is known that in "C++ community plugin" version 0.91 onward, 
Configuration setting sonar.cxx.cppncss.reportPath is no longer supported.

So i will have to downgrade the plugin lower than 0.9, and i'm not finding in official sonarqube site or any source code.

Do anybody has the Sonar C++ community plugin of any older version lesser than 0.9? please help and share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Older releases are available in maven repository:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.codehaus.sonar-plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22sonar-cxx-plugin%22

Download:

- 0.2 - http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-cxx-plugin/0.2/sonar-cxx-plugin-0.2.jar
- 0.1 - http://repo1.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/sonar-cxx-plugin/0.1/sonar-cxx-plugin-0.1.jar